# Elementary Proof Involving Inequalities

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $x\in\mathbb {R}$. Prove if $x^4 + 1 > x^9 + x$, then $ x < 1$.

I began claiming that $x \ge 1$ implies $x^4 + 1 \le x^9 + x$.

Then, I moved the terms over: $0 \le x^9 - x^4 + x - 1$.

Is this proof valid? If not, what do I need to show instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \geq 1$, $x^9\geq x^4$. So, $x^9+x\geq x^4+1$. Thus, $x^9+x < x^4+1 \implies x<1$.